# How to create a custom themed NSButton without subclassing NSButtonCell?

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

I am currently working on a custom themed `NSButton`. Every tutorial, or guide I have found requires to subclass `NSButtonCell`, even [the guide from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ControlCell/Tasks/SubclassingNSControl.html).

All of those seem to be outdated, because all cell methods in `NSControl` are [deprecated in Yosemite](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/index.html). I have not found any recommendations or guides what to use as a substitute.

This is the only statement, I could find:

> ## Gradual deprecation of NSCell
>
> Mac OS X 10.10 takes another step towards the eventual deprecation of
>   cells. Direct access to the cell of a control is discouraged, and
>   methods which allow it will be formally deprecated in a subsequent
>   release. A variety of cell-level APIs have been promoted to various
>   Control subclasses in order to provide cell-free access to important
>   functionality. NSLevelIndicator, NSTextField, NSSearchField, NSSlider,
>   and NSPathControl all have new properties for this purpose. Cell-based
>   NSTableViews are now deprecated, and view-based NSTableViews should be
>   used instead. Matrix-based NSBrowsers are also deprecated in favor of
>   the item-based interface.
>
> Excerpt from: [AppKit Release Notes for OS X v10.10](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/)

No words on `NSButton` though.

`NSTextField` supports layer backed views; because of that, I tried the same approach on my `NSButton`, but that has no effect.

```swift
var btn = NSButton(NSMakeRect(0, 0, 50, 20))
btn.wantsLayer = true
btn.bordered = false
btn.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor(calibratedWhite: 0.99, alpha: 1).CGColor
btn.layer?.borderWidth = 1
btn.layer?.borderColor = NSColor(calibratedWhite: 0.81, alpha: 1).CGColor
```

Comment: As a little side note, a cheat if you will, I have been creating custom views-- then making an invisible button on top of it.  Saves a lot of headache.

Comment: You can simply give your theme as background image of the button.

Comment: @MattyAyOh seems easy, but more like a hack. I don’t think this is the intended way to do it and I would like to know the intended way. But thanks for sharing this trick.

Comment: @SheenVempeny Yes, but this introduces other problems. I can not animate specific properties, need different versions for different resolutions and so on. Especially on simple buttons I would like to generate them by code.

Answer (score 4):

I would definitely spend more time looking into the `layer-backed view` approach. I'm not sure why it didn't work for you because there's no reason for layers not to work on an `NSButton` (effectively an `NSView` derivative).

Also weighing on looking more into layers is your mentioning of animation.

Some code extracted from a project I am working on (custom `NSButton`):

From init()...

```
    self.wantsLayer = true
    self.layerContentsRedrawPolicy = NSViewLayerContentsRedrawPolicy.OnSetNeedsDisplay

    self.layer?.borderColor = NSColor.gridColor().CGColor
    self.layer?.borderWidth = 0.5
    self.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.whiteColor().CGColor
```

You can then get fine-grained control in the display cycle specific to layers with:

```
override var wantsUpdateLayer:Bool{
    return true
}

override func updateLayer() {
    // your code here
    super.updateLayer()
}
```

If your custom button needs a shape then you can even use a CAShapeLayer below to make your backing layer a special shape...more detail to be looked into.

```
override func makeBackingLayer() -> CALayer {
    return CAShapeLayer()
}
```